# Почему Google map долго грузит детали карты в определенных координатах?

Tags: android, android-sdk, google-maps-api, google-maps

Добрый день!
Использую в android-приложении Google map. Обнаружил странную вещь: если переместить позицию карты в разные координаты, то разное время погрузки деталей карты. Позицию из Беларусии грузит мгновенно. Москва подгружается секунд 30...
Как это ускорить?

Comment: Если можна кешировать гугл - закешируйте беларусь)

Answer (score 1):

Надо полагать, что в среднем на 1 км квадратный Москвы больше инфы гугл насобирал чем на аналогичную площадь Беларуси. Засим, видать, больше данных надо подгрузить, на что требуется больше времени.

Вывод - при прочих равных ускорить невозможно в принципе. Т.е., даже закэшировав всю карту мира, из-за большей детализации Москвы она в среднем отображаться будет дольше